# Arduino C# неправильно передается строка если отправлять ее с компа на ардуино

Tags: c#, c++, arduino, arduino-uno

В общем есть приложение, в с которого я подключаюсь на ардуино и передаю строку(она является числом, так что можно использовать и int). Подключение создаю вот так:

```
serialPort.PortName = selectedPort;
serialPort.Open();
```

Отправляю данные вот так

```
serialPort.Write(Convert.ToString("a"));
```

Код ардуино:

```
String commandValue; // данные, поступаемые с последовательного порта

void setup()
{
    lcd.begin(16,2);
    lcd.backlight();

    Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop()
{
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    if (Serial.available()) {
        commandValue = Serial.read();
        lcd.clear();
        lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
        lcd.print(commandValue);
    }
    else commandValue = "No Connect";
}
```

ЖК дисплей работает исправно, проверял, 1602 дисплей. С подсветкой все нормально. Вместо текста выводит какие-то цифры, например если текст буква a - то цифра получается 97. Возможно мне нужно передавать данные по одному символу? Или можно как-то по-нормальному. Если написать:

```
lcd.print("Text");
```

то все работает нормально

Comment: Код символа `a` в [ASCII](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) таблице `0x61`, что в десятичной системе счисления означает `97`. И можно просто `serialPort.Write("a")`.

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему вот так:

**Вариант 1:**

Пожалуй лучший способ что я нашел. Работает прекрасно и никаких проблем

С#:

```
serialPort.Write(resultStr);
```

Arduino:

```
void loop() {
    if (Serial.available()) {
    commandValue = Serial.readString();
    lcd.print(commandValue);    
    }
    delay(2000);
}
```

**Вариант 2:**

Посимвольно передавать данные. Работает **хуже** чем код выше. Но может пригодиться кому-нибудь как вариант решения.

С#:

```
for(int i = 0; i<resultStr.Length; i++)
    {
        serialPort.Write(Convert.ToString(resultStr[i]));
    }
```

Раз не удается перенести целое число, то я решил переносить по одному символу, времени это занимает немного, но немного проблемно с таймингами, но у меня выводится в таймере. Думаю без таймера все будет нормально.

Arduino:

```
void loop() {
if (Serial.available()) {
    commandValue = Serial.parseInt();
    lcd.print(commandValue);
}
delay(2000);
}
```

parseInt служит для того, чтобы объединить передаваемые числа в одно многозначное. То есть если я передаю 1, потом 2, потом 3, то получится число 123.

Comment: Если вам необходимо передавать смешанные типы данных и возможно даже структуры, то есть смысл написать хедлеры для подготовки **SendablePacket** на отправку и обработки **RecievedPacket** принятого пакетов, в которых вы будете формировать из данных байт массивы и обратно, а передача уже будет байт массивами. В этом случае не будет похожих костылей и интерфейс обмена может быть расширен до бесконечности. Естественно вам потребуется писать обработчик и на стороне Ардуино. Но это всё в случае смешанных типов.